# What is the best way to store large text values?

Tags: database, h2

I have a table which contains large JSON text, each row is about 100 KB. So entire database file may grow up to 15 GB, which makes it very slow, it even takes forever to open the database. Despite the fact that `c_data` is a CLOB column.

```
create table t_data (
    id                            integer auto_increment not null,
    c_some_column_1               integer,
    c_some_column_2               integer,
    c_data                        text,
    constraint pk_t_data primary key (id)
);
```

Am I doing something wrong? Should I store the data in separate text files to keep DB as lightweight and quick as possible? Are there better solutions?

I use H2 database 1.4.197.

Comment: [Create it as a `CACHED` table](http://h2database.com/html/commands.html#create_table) - otherwise H2 tries to load the whole content into memory during startup

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name every table is a cached table by default as documentation says. So I think it won't make any difference.

Comment: Maybe you [changed](http://h2database.com/html/commands.html#set_default_table_type) the default table type

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name every, I don't think so. How can I check which value this variable set to?